# Passing complex data between activities in Android

Tags: c#, android, serialization, mvvm, xamarin

I know that this question has been asked several times before and there have been a variety of answers ranging from

1. Use the intent to pass primitive data types.
2. Implementing the **Serializable** or **Parseable** interface and handling the serialization and de-serialization in the appropriate methods. This way, it can be passed as an parameter in the intent.
3. Persisting data in **SharedPreferences** - again only supports primitive data types.
4. Saving the object as a part of the **Application** object - basically a Singleton class. I don't like this method as the application might get killed and the data would not persist.

I'm writing a cross-platform application and I have ViewModels (MVVM architecture) that need to be passed around. **Solution 4** works for me but I want to ensure that I will have data which is not dependent on the application lifecycle. I cannot implement Serializable (or) Parseable as the ViewModel consists of some objects that do not have serialization support (Reactive Extensions) - which rules out the other solutions.

Is there a better solution out there that I can use?

Comment: @commonsware - Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How about local database and you'll just have to pass the id?

Comment: You basically stated in your question that you need persistent storage of the data. That leaves you with either SharedPreferences, SQLite, or direct java file IO. How you want to pass that information around really depends which of those you choose.

Comment: Serialize it to Json and save in local storage, like others said SQLite or http://siaqodb.com/, https://github.com/aritchie/settings is handy too

Comment: @DerekBeattie I cannot serialize my file - as stated in the question above.

Comment: @AnandS Maybe not the entire VM but you can serialize (not implement ISerializable) the view model state.  See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle as an example.